# Unable show columns in msql

Tags: python, mysql

```js
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# price_retrieval.py

from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
import warnings

import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests


# Obtain a database connection to the MySQL instance
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'sec_user'
db_pass = 'password'
db_name = 'securities_master'
con = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)


def obtain_list_of_db_tickers():
    """
    Obtains a list of the ticker symbols in the database.
    """
    with con: 
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT id, ticker FROM symbol")
        data = cur.fetchall()
        return [(d[0], d[1]) for d in data]


def get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(
        ticker, start_date=(2000,1,1),
        end_date=datetime.date.today().timetuple()[0:3]
    ):
    """
    Obtains data from Yahoo Finance returns and a list of tuples.

    ticker: Yahoo Finance ticker symbol, e.g. "GOOG" for Google, Inc.
    start_date: Start date in (YYYY, M, D) format
    end_date: End date in (YYYY, M, D) format
    """
    # Construct the Yahoo URL with the correct integer query parameters
    # for start and end dates. Note that some parameters are zero-based!
    ticker_tup = (
        ticker, start_date[1]-1, start_date[2], 
        start_date[0], end_date[1]-1, end_date[2], 
        end_date[0]
    )
    yahoo_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv"
    yahoo_url += "?s=%s&a=%s&b=%s&c=%s&d=%s&e=%s&f=%s"
    yahoo_url = yahoo_url % ticker_tup

    # Try connecting to Yahoo Finance and obtaining the data
    # On failure, print an error message.
    try:
        yf_data = requests.get(yahoo_url).text.split("\n")[1:-1]
        prices = []
        for y in yf_data:
            p = y.strip().split(',')
            prices.append( 
                (datetime.datetime.strptime(p[0], '%Y-%m-%d'),
                p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6]) 
            )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not download Yahoo data: %s" % e)
    return prices


def insert_daily_data_into_db(
        data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data
    ):
    """
    Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the
    MySQL database. Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

    daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data (with 
    adj_close and volume)
    """
    # Create the time now
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    # Amend the data to include the vendor ID and symbol ID
    daily_data = [
        (data_vendor_id, symbol_id, d[0], now, now,
        d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6]) 
        for d in daily_data
    ]

    # Create the insert strings
    column_str = """data_vendor_id, symbol_id, price_date, created_date, 
                 last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, 
                 close_price, volume, adj_close_price"""
    insert_str = ("%s, " * 11)[:-2]
    final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
        (column_str, insert_str)

    # Using the MySQL connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
    with con: 
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This ignores the warnings regarding Data Truncation
    # from the Yahoo precision to Decimal(19,4) datatypes
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

    # Loop over the tickers and insert the daily historical
    # data into the database
    tickers = obtain_list_of_db_tickers()
    lentickers = len(tickers)
    for i, t in enumerate(tickers):
        print(
            "Adding data for %s: %s out of %s" % 
            (t[1], i+1, lentickers)
        )
        yf_data = get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1])
        insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)
    print("Successfully added Yahoo Finance pricing data to DB.")
```

```js
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# retrieving_data.py

from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb as mdb


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Connect to the MySQL instance
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = 'sec_user'
    db_pass = 'password'
    db_name = 'securities_master'
    con = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)

    # Select all of the historic Google adjusted close data
    sql = """SELECT dp.price_date, dp.adj_close_price
             FROM symbol AS sym
             INNER JOIN daily_price AS dp
             ON dp.symbol_id = sym.id
             WHERE sym.ticker = 'GOOG'
             ORDER BY dp.price_date ASC;"""

    # Create a pandas dataframe from the SQL query
    goog = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=con, index_col='price_date')    

    # Output the dataframe tail
    print(goog.tail())
```

```js
CREATE TABLE exchange (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  abbrev varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(255) NULL,
  country varchar(255) NULL,
  currency varchar(64) NULL,
  timezone_offset time NULL,
  created_date datetime NOT NULL,
  last_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE data_vendor (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  website_url varchar(255) NULL,
  support_email varchar(255) NULL,
  created_date datetime NOT NULL,
  last_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE symbol (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  exchange_id int NULL,
  ticker varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  instrument varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NULL,
  sector varchar(255) NULL,
  currency varchar(32) NULL,
  created_date datetime NOT NULL,
  last_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY index_exchange_id (exchange_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE daily_price (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data_vendor_id int NOT NULL,
  symbol_id int NOT NULL,
  price_date datetime NOT NULL,
  created_date datetime NOT NULL,
  last_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
  open_price decimal(19,4) NULL,
  high_price decimal(19,4) NULL,
  low_price decimal(19,4) NULL,
  close_price decimal(19,4) NULL,
  adj_close_price decimal(19,4) NULL,
  volume bigint NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY index_data_vendor_id (data_vendor_id),
  KEY index_symbol_id (symbol_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```html
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# insert_symbols.py

from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
from math import ceil

import bs4
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests


def obtain_parse_wiki_snp500():
    """
    Download and parse the Wikipedia list of S&P500 
    constituents using requests and BeautifulSoup.

    Returns a list of tuples for to add to MySQL.
    """
    # Stores the current time, for the created_at record
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    # Use requests and BeautifulSoup to download the 
    # list of S&P500 companies and obtain the symbol table
    response = requests.get(
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
    )
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    # This selects the first table, using CSS Selector syntax
    # and then ignores the header row ([1:])
    symbolslist = soup.select('table')[0].select('tr')[1:]

    # Obtain the symbol information for each 
    # row in the S&P500 constituent table
    symbols = []
    for i, symbol in enumerate(symbolslist):
        tds = symbol.select('td')
        symbols.append(
            (
                tds[0].select('a')[0].text,  # Ticker
                'stock', 
                tds[1].select('a')[0].text,  # Name
                tds[3].text,  # Sector
                'USD', now, now
            ) 
        )
    return symbols


def insert_snp500_symbols(symbols):
    """
    Insert the S&P500 symbols into the MySQL database.
    """
    # Connect to the MySQL instance
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = 'sec_user'
    db_pass = 'password'
    db_name = 'securities_master'
    con = mdb.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name)

    # Create the insert strings
    column_str = "ticker, instrument, name, sector, currency, created_date, last_updated_date"
    insert_str = ("%s, " * 7)[:-2]
    final_str = "INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
        (column_str, insert_str)
        

    # Using the MySQL connection, carry out 
    # an INSERT INTO for every symbol
    with con: 
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbols = obtain_parse_wiki_snp500()
    insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
    print("%s symbols were successfully added." % len(symbols))
```

As can be seen in the first screenshot provided below, 'ticker' is clearly shown to be one of the columns in the table symbol.  However, it returns "Empty set" as if it is not there (or at least I think that is what it implies) when I run the following code:  `SHOW COLUMNS FROM symbol LIKE 'ticker';`

The second screenshot shows code where I am running into problems (the error is "Unknown column 'ticker' in 'field list'").  This error is why I performed the test shown in screenshot 1.

----THE ABOVE PROBLEM WAS SOLVED BY ANSWER 1

Now, I am obtaining an error when running the last portion of this particular code, called 'retrieving_data'.  The output of the script should be as follows:

price_date    adj_close_price

2015-06-09      526.69

2015-06-10      536.69

2015-06-11      534.61

2015-06-12      532.33

2015-06-15      527.20

Instead, I get a bunch of runtime warnings and this meager output (see screenshot 3):

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [adj_close_price]
Index: []`

Any input as to what I may be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: Never mind, I realized the script doesn't work because yahoo no longer works.

[screenshot] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrKjG.png

[screenshot2] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD9l6.png

[screenshot3] [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XasR9.png

[screenshot4] [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrX8B.png

Comment: Is the screenshot provided?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: consider making edits in your question

Comment: I see this question has already been down voted four times.  I have actually spent several hours on this problem, and it seems like it should be so simple but obviously I must be doing something wrong because it is not working,  How can I be more clear with this question?

Comment: @corey99 For a start, consider _posting your code in the question_ and **not** in the form of a screenshot.

Comment: How is that?  Anything else I can do to make this a better post?

Comment: Don't worry too much about the downvotes. But, for future reference, try to keep your code samples as small as possible.And, show the stuff you've put into your screenshots as text (indenting four spaces to preserve their formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows column names like     `‘id‘` and `‘ticker‘` in your `symbol` table.  As far as I can see from your screenshots, your column names start and end with  the unicode character `‘` for open-single-quote. Your column is named   `‘ticker‘`, but your query references the column named `ticker` and doesn't find it.

MySQL likes to delimit column names with the backtick

```
`
```

character, which is different from the open-single-quote character.  But you don't have to delimit your column names at all as long as they aren't reserved words and don't contain spaces.

Somehow you've managed to create your table with those extra characters in your column names. Take a careful look at the way you create that table.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer!  Removing ` from each of the column names did the trick.